# RouteValueDictionary overridden by context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

If you have a route:

```
routes.MapRoute("search", "{controller}/{action}/{filter1}/{filter2}/{filter3}", _
  New With {.filter1 = "", .filter2 = "", .filter3 = ""})
```

then in a view satisfied by the route pattern with a url of `/member/search/dev/phil/hoy`, when you attempt to create another route url with only `filter1` present i.e.

```
<%=Url.RouteUrl(New RouteValueDictionary(
  New With {.controller="member",.action="search", .filter1="dev"}))%>
```

the result is the current route `/member/search/dev/phil/hoy`, not the expected trimmed route `/member/search/dev`

I have managed to work round the issue by using `RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath` method directly, but does anyone know why it works this way or is it perhaps a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following and see if it works.

Place this,

```
routes.MapRoute("search", "{controller}/{action}/{filter1}/", _
  New With {.controller="member",.action="search", .filter1="dev"})
```

..before,

```
routes.MapRoute("search", "{controller}/{action}/{filter1}/{filter2}/{filter3}", _
  New With {.filter1 = "", .filter2 = "", .filter3 = ""})
```

Specific to generic.

Answer (score 0):

the C in MVC does not stand for complex...

I believe you should not be using URLs Routes to achieve this type of functionality - you are far better off passing this kind of data as POST or GET (I prefer the former its heaps tidier) to the CONTROLLER and then sorting out the business logic from there.

How long is it going to be before your Route Maps become completely unwieldy with numerous different search combinations?